# Uniting NodeLists in DOM (java)

Tags: java, dom, xpath

Here's my code:

```
private NodeList union(NodeList left, NodeList right){

    NodeList result=null;
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!

        DocumentBuilder newBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document newDoc = newBuilder.newDocument();

        Element root = newDoc.createElement("root");
        newDoc.appendChild(root);
        if(left!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<left.getLength();i++){
                Node tmp=(Node)left.item(i).cloneNode(true);
                newDoc.adoptNode(tmp);
                newDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(tmp);
                //root.appendChild(newDoc.importNode((Node)left.item(i), true));
            }
        }
        if(right!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<right.getLength();i++){
                Node tmp=(Node)right.item(i).cloneNode(true);
                newDoc.adoptNode(tmp);
                newDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(tmp);
                //root.appendChild(newDoc.importNode((Node)right.item(i), true));
            }
        }

        result=root.getChildNodes();
    } catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In this code I'm trying to unite two NodeLists into one.

It works well, except the fact that after union, the nodes loses the context of their parent, ancestor, preceding-sibling etc... So if I'm trying to run evaluate on the result and use parent/ansector/preceding-sibling/etc axis on the result, it fails.

What should I do in order they won't lose it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A node can only exist in one document.  If you want the copied node to be in both documents you're out of luck.  You can only create a new node in the target document and move children and attributes from the old node to the new node.  Look at Document::adoptNode(Node) for what might be the easiest way to do that.